# Match groups in sed

Tags: sed, regular-expression, macos

I am trying to programatically replace the string `concat(x,y)` by the string `xy` using sed and capture groups, where `x` and `y` represent arbitrary digits.

I thought the following would do the trick :

```
echo "concat(3,2)" | sed 's!concat(\(\d\),\(\d\))!"\1\2"!'
```

I am basically trying to capture each digit in a group and output the two groups side by side. I do not understand the output I am getting from this command :

```
concat(3,2)
```

Why does my `sed` command do not have any effect ? I don't know how relevant this is, but I am on a Mac.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `sed` only understands basic regular expressions, so you have to use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`:

```
$ echo "concat(3,2)" | sed 's!concat(\([0-9]\),\([0-9]\))!"\1\2"!'
"32"
```